# Inner workings of TTY under Linux

Tags: tty

I've been trying to figure out how TTY drivers works for a while now (with full understanding each kernel's implementation may be different), and came across a nice article: [The TTY demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php)

I notice however that it claims xterm does not have a `stdin`, `stdout` or `stderr`. How does xterm and other terminal emulators get the input from bash and other child processes so it can print to the window? Does the terminal emulator have a connection to a TTY driver at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the claim that `xterm(1)` has no `stdin`, `stdout`, or `stderr` makes much sense. And, just skimming that article, I think they were left blank on the diagram because they didn't figure much into what he was describing.

You can check your own terminals' file descriptors easily enough. The `urxvt(1)` terminals that I normally use look like this:

```
lrwx------ 1 sarnold sarnold 64 2011-11-10 21:33 0 -> /home/sarnold/.xsession-errors
lrwx------ 1 sarnold sarnold 64 2011-11-10 21:33 1 -> /home/sarnold/.xsession-errors
lrwx------ 1 sarnold sarnold 64 2011-11-10 21:33 2 -> /home/sarnold/.xsession-errors
```

An `xterm(1)` I started from one of those `urxvt(1)` terminals looks like this:

```
lrwx------ 1 sarnold sarnold 64 2011-11-15 16:45 0 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 sarnold sarnold 64 2011-11-15 16:45 1 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 sarnold sarnold 64 2011-11-15 16:45 2 -> /dev/pts/1
```

And an `xterm(1)` I started using my window manager's `dmenu(1)` launcher looks like this:

```
lrwx------ 1 sarnold sarnold 64 2011-11-15 16:46 0 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 sarnold sarnold 64 2011-11-15 16:46 1 -> /home/sarnold/.xsession-errors
lrwx------ 1 sarnold sarnold 64 2011-11-15 16:46 2 -> /home/sarnold/.xsession-errors
```

The important part to remember about `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` is that they are completely unrelated to the *graphical display* that the terminal emulators offer. If your terminal program needs to write an error to `stderr`, say via `perror(3)`, its output might go to the terminal where you started it or to a session error log such as `~/.xsession-errors`. If you log in via `ssh(1)` and start your `xterm(1)` like this:

```
DISPLAY=:1 xterm -e 'echo hello ; sleep 10`
```

You'll see it start up and display `hello`. (Assuming your `DISPLAY` matches mine.) If you change the command to:

```
DISPLAY=:1 xterm -fn fiddly -e 'echo hello ; sleep 10'
```

You'll see that the error message about the incorrect font is sent to the terminal where you started `xterm(1)` -- not to its own graphical interface. (This is a bit funny, because if you change `SHELL` to something that doesn't exist, or attempt to execute something that doesn't exist, the error message will be printed within the graphical window instead of to the standard error.)

A file that is also open in my terminal emulators is `ptmx(4)`:

```
lrwx------ 1 sarnold sarnold 64 2011-11-10 21:33 0 -> /home/sarnold/.xsession-errors
lrwx------ 1 sarnold sarnold 64 2011-11-10 21:33 1 -> /home/sarnold/.xsession-errors
lrwx------ 1 sarnold sarnold 64 2011-11-10 21:33 2 -> /home/sarnold/.xsession-errors
lrwx------ 1 sarnold sarnold 64 2011-11-10 21:33 3 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lr-x------ 1 sarnold sarnold 64 2011-11-10 21:33 4 -> pipe:[16398]
l-wx------ 1 sarnold sarnold 64 2011-11-10 21:33 5 -> pipe:[16398]
lrwx------ 1 sarnold sarnold 64 2011-11-10 21:33 6 -> socket:[16399]
lrwx------ 1 sarnold sarnold 64 2011-11-10 21:33 7 -> /dev/ptmx
```

Opening the `ptmx(4)` device gives the terminal emulator the `pipe` connections for the PTY master and slave. It is to these `pipe`s that the terminal emulator software communicates with the clients and the kernel.

I can't do the `tty` layer justice; I strongly recommend reading the `pty` section from [Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment, 2nd edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201433079) for full details. The book (and [source code](http://www.apuebook.com/) include writing your own `pty` driver which can be used to implement `script(1)`-like functionality or tricking the standard C IO streams into using line-buffering rather than block-buffering when the program doesn't provide any command line options to control this natively.

Comment: Just one last question: if `stderr` is set to something like `/dev/pts/1`, would that write to the graphical display?

Comment: In the case of my earlier examples, the `/dev/pts/1` was supplied by a _different_ terminal emulator. I have to admit I've never thought about connecting a terminals `stderr` or `stdout` to the terminal device that _it_ owns, but it probably wouldn't be too hard to modify one of the emulators to give it a shot. You might want to try [`st`](http://st.suckless.org/), from the `suckless.org` team -- it is far clearer code than `xterm(1)`.

Comment: The side-direction of my question was actually to figure out how terminal emulators get the output from child processes rather than change how they do now; I'll give `st` a read and see what I can discover, though.